# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService' in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

In a spring boot application, I have a `AuditorAwareInterface` that use an `@Autowired` `userService`.

It look like:

```java
@Configuration
public class AuditorAwareConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Long> auditorAware() {
        return new AuditorAware<Long>() {

            @Autowired
            private UserService userService;

            @Override
            public Long getCurrentAuditor() {
                SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
                Authentication authentication = ctx.getAuthentication();

                if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                    return null;
                }

                User user = null;
                Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

                if (principal.getClass().equals(User.class)) {
                    user = (User) principal;
                } else if (principal.getClass().equals(InetOrgPerson.class)) {
                    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
                    String username = userDetails.getUsername();
                    UserDTO cond = new UserDTO();
                    cond.setUsername(username);
                    user = userService.findBasicOne(cond);
                }

                if (null == user) {
                    return null;
                }

                return user.getId();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It work fine, but within a controller unit test, I have the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'auditorAware': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService';
```

I have tried to initialize the context in my test using `@ContextConfiguration`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        CompanyManagement.class,
        CompanyManagementConfig.class,
        CompanyController.class,
+        UserService.class,
}, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

How can I fix my unit test?

Comment: I think the `AuditorAwareConfiguration` could just be fixed with a different synthax, is there anything that load after `@Configuration`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a unit test. It's an integration test.

**Why it's not working?**

You should specify inside the @ContextConfiguration only config files, eg. files that contain bean declarations.

**How to fix?**

Create a separate configuration file that will be used for that particular integration test (should be under `src/test/`)

If UserService has `@Component` annotation (or one of the children) and created by the component scan:

```
  @ComponentScan({"package where UserService class located"})    
  public class SomeSpecificIntergarionTestConfig {
  }
```

If UserService is created in some of java-config explicitly:

```
public class SomeSpecificIntergarionTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserService userService{
      return new UserService();
    }
}
```

Then add this config into context configuration annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
 SomeSpecificIntergarionTestConfig.class,
 rest of configs. 
})
```

**Important**: to avoid component scan issues, it's better to not mark test configs with the `@Configuration` annotation